# Applying "this" to a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Instead of repeating a function for every ID of my elements, I would like to use "this" to adjust the CSS of an internal element. For instance, this is how far I've gotten (doesn't work).

```
$(".parent").hover(function() {
$("this").find(".child").css("height","150px")
});
```

How can I become a more efficient coder and use "this"?

Comment: You've got it. Just don't use the quotes: `$(this)...`

Comment: You could also do this with just css. `.parent:hover .child {height:150px;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove quotations from "this" and it'll work. A common mistake :)

**code** like this:

```
$(this).find(".child").css("height","150px")
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
$(".parent").hover(function() {
      $(this).find(".child").css("height","150px")
});
```

So that there are no quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a solution that does not require jQuery:

```
someElement.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.target.children);

    children.forEach(function(child) {
        child.style.height = '150px';
    });
}, false);
```